# Is there a way to mirror Cassandra table across different keyspaces

Tags: cassandra, nosql

Requirement:
We have a particular transaction table retail_mapping in cassandra keyspace "account". 
We have another keyspace "dp" where the exact table data "retail_mapping" needs to be replicated and accessed by micro-services.

1) Is there any way we can create a mirror table retail_mapping in dp keyspace coming from account keyspace.
2) Any data which is persisted in account keyspace also needs to be copied into dp keyspace immediately

Comment: Can you explain why do you need this? Separating workloads, separating users, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you could create a snapshot (to do on each nodes) and copy the data file to the other table, followed by a nodetool refresh.

For your second question, the best is to achieve that at the application layer. If that s not an option then your best option is to look at Cassandra triggers.